# Tabbar and Topbar not working as expected

Tags: trigger.io

Using trigger.io to build a HTML5 app.

Using topbar and tabbar native UI features and encountering below issues.

**Topbar**

For android: The title image is reduced a lot and becomes like a small icon. Whereas for IOS works fine. I am using android 4.1.2 Galaxt note 2 to test the apk file.

Is there an optimum image size for title image so that it does not get reduced?

**Tabbar**

Unable to add Tabbar buttons in both Android and IOS.
Below is the exact js code I am using

```
forge.tabbar.addButton({
  icon: "img/IMG_0045.png",
  text: "First",
  index: 0
}, function (button) {
  button.setActive();
  button.onPressed.addListener(function () {
    alert("First");
  });
});

forge.tabbar.addButton({
  icon: "img/IMG_0047.png",
  text: "Second",
  index: 1
}, function (button) {
  button.onPressed.addListener(function () {
    alert("Second");
  });
});
```

Please advice!!

Answer (score 0):

For the topbar the recommended image size is 100PX  in height as described on the style portion of the docs

https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/topbar.html

Its all the way at the bottom of that page under style guidlines

As for the button in the tabbar, do you see a tabbar or bar just with no buttons?

Comment: I see a bar with no buttons